# How to forbid ssh connection after sudo -u

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, sudoedit

After ssh login, user with UserName makes `$ sudo -u localusername -i` and `$ ssh localusername@someserver`

How to forbid `ssh localusername@someserver` for UserName via `sudo -u localusername` but permit it for localusername without switching from sudo.

`ssh localusername@someserver` with key pair.

Comment: I bet you cannot. `localusername` must have read-access to the file containing its private key and there is no mechanism that would make it dependent on how a process was executed.

Comment: i guess you're right but I need to try find some way

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is realistically possible. Maybe if you explained why you need to do this, someone could help you with your actual goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you grant a user access to login to an account, you grant full access to that account and any means you try to detect the difference can easily be overcome with basic environment manipulations.

If you wish to block the login and ssh, you could add instructions in your `/etc/sudoers` file such as:

```
UserName ALL = !/bin/bash
UserName ALL = !/bin/sh
UserName ALL = !/usr/bin/ssh
```